# Why does a Nuxt 2 server open multiple multi-threaded node processes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

This may be a rookie question, but I'm dealing with a Nuxt 2 server that I'm just currently running in localhost. It's for a large project that also runs in production. I'm encountering an unusual number of node processes being created on running the project. The app is being run in SSR mode with multiple pages/components. [image: node processes]

Above is a picture of the processes. These are all being generated from a single Nuxt 2 server. Can someone tell me why I have six multithreaded processes on this one server? Is this normal or something I should look into to optimize performance on my site?

I was expecting maybe one or two node processes. I've tried to dig into the codebase and figure out what is causing this and I've come up with a blank.